# Error in launching jnlp

Tags: java, jnlp

While launching `JNLP` file, I am getting following error.

> Could not create java virtual machine. A fatal exception has occurred.
>   Program will exit.

This problem sometimes goes away after restarting. Any quick-fix for this error ?

Comment: Possible problem is that not enough memory is available to launch the JVM with the memory parameters you have passed. Without more information it is hard to say much (what parameters do you use, what JVM, etc.)

Comment: This error message normally appears when invalid options are passed to the JVM. Have you set any special vm arguments in your configuration?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). When you've fixed any errors it reports, post the content as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40285787/edit).